# how would I write this function in a nicer way?

Tags: bash

this is some bash code I wrote to check for an existing directory and make it if it didn't exist. It seems a bit clunky to me, so I'm wondering if people have tips??

```
dir_check () {
    # this is a function for checking if a simulation directory exists and if 
    for i in $@
    do
        vers_num=1
        # echo "$i \n"
        if [ -d "$i" ]; then
            if [ -d "$i-run-$vers_num" ]; then
                while [ -d "$i-run-$vers_num" ]; do
                    ((vers_num++))
                    new_dir="$i-run-$vers_num"
                done
            else
                new_dir="$i-run-$vers_num"
            fi

            mkdir "$new_dir"
            echo "$new_dir created"
        else 
            mkdir $i
            echo "$i created"
        
        fi

    done
}
```

just looking for feedback on this code

Comment: If this is otherwise working code then you may be looking for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I find your code nice and great. It's readable. After 10 seconds, I knew what is going on. I would keep it. I would add `local vers_num new_dir i` and would use `[[` instead of `[` and quote both `$i` and `$@` and check with shellcheck. I think `if [ -d "$i-run-$vers_num" ]; then` can be removed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! @David, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You could have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *is for* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: Is it really important, the the version number does not have leading zeroes?

Comment: The bare `$@` is an error; probably try https://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

Comment: You will want leading zeros to preserve directory sort order. In bash `printf -v d_vers_num "%03d" "$((vers_num++))"` will create `d_vers_num=001` from `vers_num=1` and advance `vers_num` by 1 afterwards. Use `new_dir="$i-run-$d_vers_num"` Now when you list the directory your subdirectory numbers will be in natural order. (instead of `1, 10, 11, ..., 2 ...`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- use continue to shorten the logic
- calculate the next version with a pipeline
- if it doesn't exist, echo message and create

```
dir_check() {
  for i in "$@"
  do
    test ! -d "$i" && { mkdir $i ; continue ; }
    local ver=$( { ls -d "$i"-run-* 2>&- || echo 0; }  | sed "s:$i-run-::" | sort -nr | head -1)
    ((ver++))
    test ! -d "$i-run-$ver" && { mkdir "$i-run-$ver" ; echo "$i-run-$ver 
  created" ; }
  done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some comments are opinions depend on the style, take it or leave it.

```
dir_check () {
    # local variable to avoid side effects
    # a meaningful name rather than 'i'
    local dir
    for dir in "$@"; do

        # the condition was inverted
        # to avoid the else far from condition
        # and allows to reduce nesting with continue, break or return depending on the situation
        if [[ ! -d "$dir" ]]; then
            mkdir "$dir"
            echo "$dir created"
            continue
        fi
        
        local vers_num=1 new_dir
        # to avoid repeating instruction can be put in a sequence
        # while or until only the exit status used for the condition is the last of the sequence 
        until new_dir="$dir-run-$((vers_num++))"; [[ ! -d "$new_dir" ]]; do
            :
        done

        mkdir "$new_dir"
        echo "$new_dir created"

    done
}
```